# Python Socket Timeout

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server

I am currently using `socket.recv` to recieve a message from a server with my client. Is there any way, if no message has been recieved for 5 seconds, to display a custom error and close the connection + client?

Comment: [`settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)

Comment: Use [`socket.settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) before you perform a blocking operation to control its timeout. So in your case it sounds like you don't want a timeout for `connect()`, but one for `recv()`.

Comment: You also might want to look into non blocking sockets, I had a great deal of joy with them (:

Answer (score 1):

Use [`socket.settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) before you perform a blocking operation to control its timeout. So in your case it sounds like you don't want a timeout for `connect()`, but one for `recv()`.